# TypeError: $http.get(...).then(...).controller is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I'm building an app to dynamically load and display data from a database in AngularJS, but when I try to access my ASP.Net(.ASMX web service) (using $http.get()), I receive errrors: TypeError: $http.get(...).then(...).controller is not a function
Please help....

**Controller code:**

```
.controller("studentsController", function ($scope, $http ) {
    $http.get("StudentService.asmx/GetAllStudents")
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.students = response.data;
    })
```

**students.html code:**

```
<h1>List of Students</</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="student in students">
            {{student.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to add in a bit more of the code around where you are defining the controller? Based on the error message it looks like the code above it has got a syntax error so your `.controller` is being set on the result of a promise further up the code

Comment: It looks like your angular module where you call `.controller(..)` is not defined properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that your Web service is working properly.

**Change your controller code in the following way:**

```
angular.module('myapp')
.controller("studentsController",['$scope', '$http', function (scope, http ) {
    http.get("StudentService.asmx/GetAllStudents")
        .success(function(data) {
          scope.students = data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
           console.error('Response error', status, data);
        })
}]);
```

Not tested, but should work.

Comment: After doing the controller code changes , application is working fine.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject $http service in angular service and from controller,intialize it and make call to web service.
or
you can wrap your code within (function(){(your angular controller)})().

Comment: I believe the OP is already doing this, otherwise `$http.get()` would be undefined.