# Inject json file form other website using angular not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to inject the json form wordpress plugin "JSON-API". 
In other words I just want to make news-panel on my website, but I want make my life easier and write post on easy wysiwyg editor.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="maincontroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="lightblue">
        <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainController">
            <div id="content">
                <div ng-repeat="content in contents">
                    <h2>{{content.title}}</h2>
                    <p>{{content.date}}</p>
                    <p>{{content.content}}</p>
                    <p>{{content.url}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

mainController.js:

```
var myapp=angular.module('mainApp',[]);
myapp.controller('mainController',function($scope,$http){

    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://192.168.0.16/wordpress/?json=1'}).
        then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.contents=data[0];
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {  
             $scope.contents = [{heading:"Error",description:"JSON invalid"}];        
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, nothing displays just error in console

```
angular.js:14328TypeError: $http(...).then(...).error is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (maincontroller.js:9)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4842)
    at R.instance (angular.js:10695)
    at n (angular.js:9572)
    at g (angular.js:8881)
    at angular.js:8746
    at angular.js:1843
    at m.$eval (angular.js:17972)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:18072)
    at angular.js:1841
```

any ideas guys?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585937/typeerror-http-get-then-controller-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrongly using `then`

```
.then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

And you can minimize `$http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://192.168.0.16/wordpress/?json=1'})` by `$http.get('http://192.168.0.16/wordpress/?json=1')`

---

Replace your controller by the following code

```
var myapp=angular.module('mainApp',[]);
myapp.controller('mainController',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('http://192.168.0.16/wordpress/?json=1').then(function(response){
        $scope.contents = response[0];
    }, function(error){
        $scope.contents = [{heading:"Error",description:"JSON invalid"}]; 
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

kindly change `then` to `success`

```
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.contents=data[0];
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $http.get("url",{}).
     then(function(response){
         alert("success");
     }, function myError(response) {
            alert("error");
        });
 try this hope it should work.
```